# How to see at what time I added a contact to my phone (android)

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have an alcatel one touch android phone, I am trying to figure out if its possible to see the date and time of when I added a contact (phone number) to the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can get last contact update when retrieving `Contact` with [`CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP) but [retrieving all contact details](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html#RetrieveAll) does not seem to include creation date in [`Contacts API`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html).

**NOTE**: be sure to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: How do I retrieve contact that way? Through the phone??

Comment: [Click here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html#RetrieveAll) via java, as you tagged in your question

Comment: CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP this attribute also updates when somebody calls on that number.

Comment: @AjayPrajapati True, it can change for many reasons, it's not reliable